# Why curl giving 1020 error while postman giving response

Tags: php, api, curl

`I have sent a GET (Also POST) method to get data from api but the response is error 1020 and at the same time post man tried and its giving response then what is wrong here.
I am not able to share the api url due to security reasons.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'url_with_parameter',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Cookie: PHPSESSID=f1r22a2srpgamnidkflgqsuem2; csrf_token=c31d6332c0066fa652b79948c43e5dd7_d5ec9637ea9c6914f3cebeab7fa4ad4d',
        'Host' => "localhost",
        'User-Agent' => 'PostmanRuntime/7.31.0',
        'Accept' => '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: In postman you can get it to generate a PHP curl script.  Try generating it from your working call and see what the differences are.

Comment: i have genereted code from postman, but its giving same error

Comment: that answer is not working for me

Comment: Look at the hidden headers in postman and see if adding them make a difference.

Comment: I have updated my php curl code with code generated from postman with hidden headers

Answer (score 0):

When 1020 error is returned by curl, it means typically that the request was blocked by security settings, which can include challenges like CAPTCHAs or browser checks.

Try to add UA header into your curl request, like

```
$headers = [
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
];

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Its worked Thanks , May i know what happend when i add this statment, Thank you @Dimitry and all other for the help

Comment: What do you mean by the question "what happened?"?

By default, the curl request pass the UA header as User-Agent: curl/<version>. Most likely, there is a security protection on the server side that rejects such requests.