# API returns functions, how to await and parse JSON with UrlFetchApp

Tags: json, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am working on a script and am just testing the API calls with this script:

```
function floorGrab(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var helpSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Helper");
  var urls = helpSheet.getRange("aa2:aa").getDisplayValues();
  console.log(urls[0]);
  var options = {
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
                }
  var rawData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[0], options);
  console.log(rawData);
  var data = JSON.parse(rawData);
  console.log(data);
}
```

The URL in this example is: https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/sft/markets/4YjkU4KrCnWhQ7DhMNLkUqeJjdhgK2xZYYmt5MgNfPYq?name=Pipelia-Wing

When visiting this site, the JSON is easily loaded. But when calling it, it returns this which can't be parsed, of course:

```
    { toString: [Function],
    getResponseCode: [Function],
    getContent: [Function],
    getAllHeaders: [Function],
    getHeaders: [Function],
    getContentText: [Function],
    getBlob: [Function],
    getAs: [Function] }
```

Is there a way in Appscript to get the page to load fully first, and then grab the JSON?
I've tried many different options, such as adding an Origin, stringifying the data within the options, requesting JSON, etc. But everything returns the same.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are not able to parse the JSON is that the `request failed`.
Since you set the option `muteHttpExceptions` to true in the code above, you are unable to see the error response.

In [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) if this option is set to true;

> the fetch doesn't throw an exception if the response code
> indicates failure, and instead returns the [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response).

That is why when you have `console.log(rawData)` the output you are seeing is the [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)

```
{ toString: [Function],
getResponseCode: [Function],
getContent: [Function],
getAllHeaders: [Function],
getHeaders: [Function],
getContentText: [Function],
getBlob: [Function],
getAs: [Function] }
```

### Code:

I have tried calling the API from your example without adding the option `muteHttpExceptions`

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/sft/markets/4YjkU4KrCnWhQ7DhMNLkUqeJjdhgK2xZYYmt5MgNfPYq?name=Pipelia-Wing'
  var rawData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  console.log(rawData)
}
```

### Execution log:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io
> returned code 403. Truncated server response: error code: 1020 (use
> muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

### HTTP response Code (403):

> The [HTTP 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) Forbidden response status code indicates that the server
> understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

You may want to see this [thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/147521409/what-is-403-error?hl=en) for possible fixes in this error. I also added other references below that may be helpful in fixing the error.

### Error Code (1020):

> [Error 1020](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/error-1020-access-denied/) Access Denied is caused when a firewall rule has been
> violated on a site protected by Cloudflare. It can be triggered if a
> site visitor tries to directly access an endpoint that is protected.

I happened to stumble upon a similar case on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75498863/why-curl-giving-1020-error-while-postman-giving-response) regarding error 1020 and the answer suggested to add `UserAgent header` on your request. You may want to try this approach.

I have also added below the list of sites that discuss the possible fixes to this error.

### References:

**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with all of the sites suggested.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Error 403 possible fixes:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/147521409/what-is-403-error?hl=en

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-fix-403-forbidden-error-on-google-chrome/

https://www.howtogeek.com/357785/what-is-a-403-forbidden-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/

Error 1020 possible fixes:

[Why curl giving 1020 error while postman giving response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75498863/why-curl-giving-1020-error-while-postman-giving-response)

[curl 1020 error when trying to scrape page using bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65426618/curl-1020-error-when-trying-to-scrape-page-using-bash-script)

[https://rockcontent.com/blog/error-1020-access-denied/#:~:text=Wrap%20Up-,What%20is%20Error%201020%20Access%20Denied%3F,an%20endpoint%20that%20is%20protected](https://rockcontent.com/blog/error-1020-access-denied/#:%7E:text=Wrap%20Up-,What%20is%20Error%201020%20Access%20Denied%3F,an%20endpoint%20that%20is%20protected).

https://www.makeuseof.com/cloudflare-error-1020-access-denied-fix/